# QuoteLineItem.product_Code__c is a field that is not writeable in Test Class

Tags: salesforce-id, unit-test, quote

I'm creating a test class right now and one of the things I need to test is whether the ProductCode of a quotelineItem for a certain Quote starts with 'MA' or not. However, when I create a new test class, I can't specify the product code for a QuoteLineItem. How should I go about doing this so that I can properly test out my class?

Here is what I'm attempting to do right now but I'm getting an error saying "Field is not writeable: QuoteLineItem.product_Code__c".

```
    Product2 testProduct1 = TestUtil.initProduct2(); //This is my test utility class where I initialize any and all objects that I will need during a test class.

   List<QuoteLineItem> qlis=[Select Id,QuoteId from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId=:quoteId];//new List<QuoteLineItem>{qlitem,qlitem2};
        for (QuoteLineItem q:qlis){
            if (q.Product_Code__c==null){
                String qProductCode='MAR-3232-2323';
                q.Product_Code__c=testProduct1.ProductCode;
// and I have also tried
                q.Product_Code__c=qProductCode;
//both of these methods do not work when trying to set the Product Code for a quoteLineItem.
            }
        }
```

Whats the proper way of going about this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is your custom field product_code__c a formula field?  If so, you can't set it in the testmethod.

`QuoteLineItem` references its product code via field `PricebookEntryId` that in turn references a `Product2` SObject. If you want to set up test data in QuoteLineItem, you will need to set `QuoteLineItem.pricebookEntryId` to be the ID of a `PricebookEntry` for the given combination of `Pricebook2 - Currency - Product2` that you wish to test with